# Wired card not connecting after trying to connect

Tags: networking, 12.10

I have an Ubuntu 12.10 PC. When I plug in my internet cable it starts connecting and after a minute it says it can't connect. I tried different cables but nothing works. Wlan works.
I think it's the network driver but I don't know how to install/update it.
Here's the `ifconfig` info (if it helps):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:6c:39:2a:8d  
      inet6 addr: fe80::201:6cff:fe39:2a8d/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2011 errors:0 dropped:362 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:586 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:175452 (175.4 KB)  TX bytes:147211 (147.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:9779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8460080 (8.4 MB)  TX bytes:8460080 (8.4 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:10:74:35:99:9d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a10:74ff:fe35:999d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1790 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:401664 (401.6 KB)  TX bytes:2898773 (2.8 MB)
```

Comment: show me configuration of /etc/network/interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - and for some reason couldn't duplicate it with any kind of consistency.  It would just stop working for a bit, then work again, then stop again.  Pretty annoying.

I went into the Network Settings and ignored IPv6, and it *seems* to have fixed the problem.  Haven't had an outage since I did this.  Maybe it'll help?  As always, YMMV.

Happy holidays!

-Jose

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar: Ubuntu 12.10 aka Quantal Quetzal and at first I had a wired connection and after installing updates the connection was no more.
I did everything I could retrieve from the internet to solve this: settings of the connection, drivers (via USB stick), altering obscure files etc.

But one thing suddenly struck me: what if the problem does not come from the inside of the system? ROUTER! I restarted the router and voila, problem solved. Than I had some other fun problems to solve, but it worked.